# Text Selected Listener In EditText Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to implement a listener who listens to text selections in EditText may be like `onTextSelected()`,
Actually, I have a bottom navigation bar [BOLD:ITALIC:UNDERLINE:RESET ] and when the user selects any text and click the bottom navigation's item it will format the text. But when the text is selected softkey is popped up which hides the Navigation Bar. So the use of the listener will be for hiding the keyboard when text is selected.

So I tried to create a custom EditText:-

```
public class TextField extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{
String TAG = "TextField"
public TextField(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TextField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    Log.d(TAG,"onSelectionChanged");
}}
```

But it is logging every time I type something on the softkey

Any Solutions??

Comment: What do you mean of text selection here ?
can you explain briefly, what's you want to do?

Comment: See my updated question @Sunny